# Book for Analysis in $R^n$?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am actually looking for a specific book that I read in library in 2013 may be so my memory has faded but I remember the title of book, which is "Analysis in $R^n$", it was a fat green book, and the name of the author was bit lengthy. May be it was by De Gruyter, not sure. But because of $R^n$ in the name it is being impossible to find it using google or amazon, or any other site and none of the threads here on MSE mentions it.

Maybe someone here can recall the author's name and help me. It was a really good introductory book for the subject to step in.

P.S. This question might not be appropriate according to the guidelines of the tags used, so no offence will be taken if downvoted or closed. I just really need that name.

Comment: May be you already know this, but De Gruyter is a publishing house. Also, are you still in touch with any student or colleague who can check out the library ? Does the library have a website or phone number ? In any case there are many excellent intro books out there. After all, if you can't be with  the one you love, love the one you are with

Comment: Here are two green books on multivariable calculus: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7672, https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764374723

Comment: In mathscinet there is no book with that title listed. The closest title I could find was Anaylsis in Euclidean Space by Kenneth Hoffman.

Comment: Analysis with Mathematica® Volume 2 Multi-variable Calculus seems to have a green cover https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110660395/html

Comment: While ["Analysis in $R^n$: Theory and Exercises"](https://www.lap-publishing.com/catalog/details/store/gb/book/978-620-2-92342-2/analysis-in-rn-theory-and-exercises) is published by LAP but not with a green cover

Comment: @Bhaskar Vashishth one of  upcoming books of S.Kumresen on  analysis in $R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Shivering Soldier. It is https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7672 by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis.

Apparantly Analysis in $R^n$ was the name of the course for which I found this book as now I recall. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.